# "Prove that if G is a finite group and H is a proper normal subgroup of largest order, then G/H is simple."

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if G is a finite group and H is a proper normal subgroup of largest order, then G/H is simple.

how to reach G/H . ITS FROM GALLIAN ?

Comment: This question is actually only the backward step of a much more useful fact, that $G/H$ is simple $\iff$ $H \lhd G$ is maximal. All of the answers in this SE thread will satisfy your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161570/h-is-a-maximal-normal-subgroup-of-g-if-and-only-if-g-h-is-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H$ is maximal wrt normal and order, then one cannot find a normal subgroup $K$ with $H \subsetneq K \subsetneq G$. Hence $G/H$ is simple.

Comment: You intend strict inclusions I think

Comment: Geoff, absolutely, contradicting maximality.

Comment: Yes, your intention was clear, but your notation allows $K =H$ or $K=G. $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The inverse image of a normal subgroup of $G/H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $H$. Try to argue that this inverse image has to be $G$ or $H$.